# Surjective function

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group with identity element e and let $K$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of $G$ with $K∩N=e$.

I know that $nk=nk$ And the representation of an element in $K×N$ in form $kn$ is unique for all $k∈K$ and $n∈N$.

How can I show the function

$φ:(K×N)→(K⊕N)$ be defined by $φ(kn)=(k,n)$.

is surjective?

Comment: For each pair $(k,n)$, it always has preimage, so $\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: You ask the **exactly** same question you did less than 45 minutes ago, and with exactly the same mistake in the third line...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surjectivity is immediate from the definiton of $\phi$. For a generic element in $K⊕N$, say $(k,n)$ you need an element $g$ of $G$ such that $\phi(g)=(k,n)$. The choice $g:=kn$ works. What you said in the first part of the question shows that $\phi$ is well defined. If you want, you could also check that $\phi$ is a morphism (i.e. it preserves group operation: $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$), and that it is bijective.